# MySql, use group by with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I want to add a WHERE clause to my statement, but the problem is,
when I add the WHERE clause, I get an error "Invalid use of group function".

I also tried to replace the WHERE clause and write the condition into the 
`JOIN .. ON` part, but the error is still there.

I want to add the condition so that only the rows " SUM(res.ReservationID) = 2" are returned.

```
-- works but we only want to get the rows in which the SUM = 2
SELECT ctr.ID, ctr.LastName, ctr.FirstName, SUM(res.ReservationID) as ReservierteSitze
FROM customer as ctr
INNER JOIN reservation AS res ON ctr.ID = res.CustomerID
Group by ctr.ID;
```

Comment: Because WHERE is evaluated before GROUP BY, so you can't use aggregate functions there.

Comment: Still struggling? See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ctr.ID, ctr.LastName, ctr.FirstName, SUM(res.ReservationID) as ReservierteSitze
FROM customer as ctr
INNER JOIN reservation AS res ON ctr.ID = res.CustomerID
Group by ctr.ID
HAVING ReservierteSitze = 2;
```

The `HAVING` clause is like a where clause for the `GROUP BY` (applies to the groupings)

You can still have a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY` clause, but that only applies to the individual rows before the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

having(Aggregation function condition processing)